# exec() params /dev/null and ampersand on both Windows and Linux?

Tags: php, exec, background-process

From [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) manual page:

> If a program is started with this function, in order for it to
>   continue running in the background, the output of the program must be
>   redirected to a file or another output stream. Failing to do so will
>   cause PHP to hang until the execution of the program ends.

So, it seems i should **redirect output** to something and add **ampersand** under Linux, to make my script **truly running in background**.

How i'm supposed to "translate" `/dev/null` and `&` for Windows? Any chance to use [`php://`](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) to make it OS safe?

```
exec('php ' . __DIR__ . '/script.php > /dev/null &');
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$oExec = $WshShell->Run("cmd /C dir /S %windir%", 0, false);
```

Comment: Well i was looking for something that could work on both Windows and Linux, but thanks anyway.